# Tax deduction in Austria for travelling back home to Italy

Tags: taxes, austria, tax-deductions

I'm an Italian citizen living in Austria for work. I took my residence here but now one of my parents is disabled and I have to go back home every two weeks. It's very expensive and I would like to know if it's possible to detract the expenses from taxes.